# ْQT Creator to use Desktop kit get Error with :“Application finished with exit code 126.”

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, qt

I am using the QT Creator for my laptop (Linux LMDE 3 Cindy OS) And for Raspberry Cross-compiling.

I have installed the QT based of [this instruction](https://mechatronicsblog.com/cross-compile-and-deploy-qt-5-12-for-raspberry-pi/) and by this setting:

```
    mkdir ~/raspi
    cd ~/raspi
    git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools
    mkdir sysroot sysroot/usr sysroot/opt

    rsync -avz pi@raspberrypi_ip:/lib sysroot
    rsync -avz pi@raspberrypi_ip:/usr/include sysroot/usr
    rsync -avz pi@raspberrypi_ip:/usr/lib sysroot/usr
    rsync -avz pi@raspberrypi_ip:/opt/vc sysroot/opt
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.3/single/ qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3.tar.xz
tar xvf  qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3.tar.xz
cd  qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3
```

> ./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++
>   -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
>   -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -no-use-gold-linker -v -no-gbm

```
    make
    make install
```

but when i go to my **QT Creator** and i have built a sample **Qt Widget Application**.
My  `desktop2.pro` file is this kind:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-05-29T19:53:02
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = desktop2
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /home/so/Desktop/trash/desktop1/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

SO when i want to use my **Desktop Kit** and want to run it in my PC (not in Raspberry), i get this Error:

```
20:46:55: Starting /home/so/Desktop/trash/desktop1/desktop2/bin/desktop2 ...
bash: /home/so/Desktop/trash/desktop1/desktop2/bin/desktop2: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
bash: /home/so/Desktop/trash/desktop1/desktop2/bin/desktop2: Success
20:46:55: Application finished with exit code 126.
```

My **Qt Version is** shown Below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3w6e.png)

My **Desktop kit setting i**s shown blown:
[Desktop kit setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8dcM.png)

AND my **Desktop PC SS Device setting** is shown below:

[Desktop PC SS Device setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Vmu.png)

AND **My GCC Compiler setting** shown below:
[GCC Compiler setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrK3W.png)

AND My **qt Raspberry Compiler** setting is shown Below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hon6T.png)

- My Guesses is there is some conflict between The GCC Compiler AND Qt
  Version Which is `V 5.12.3`. So must i use lower **Qt** version?
- Or i Must install again that qt Version at new folder with new
  Configuration setting?
- Or what any other recommendation?

My this question link at qt community:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/103462/qt-creator-error-with-application-finished-with-exit-code-126

UPDATE: Near the Desktop kit name in Qt Creator GUI there is one red caution mark which when i hover my mouse on it show this information:

[Error: The compiler "GCC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qqin.jpg)

by this error:

```
Error: The compiler "GCC (C++,X86 64bit in /usr/bin)" (X86-linux-generic-elf-64bit) cannot produce code for the Qt Version "Qt 5.12.3 (qt5)" (arm-linux-generic-elf-32bit).
```

Excuses me,I know the cross-compiling is to write code in my Linux OS and run in for example my Raspberry, but as i mentioned  i don't want to do this now i need to test my codes via my laptop Linux OS ( (Via Desktop Kit). So how could i do that? must i install new qt v5.12.3 with new configuration?, or could i use new GCC compiler setting to for my Desktop Kit?

Excuses me,I am newbie in Qt.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: use command `file` to check if your binary file (`desktop2`) is compatible with your system and your machine (CPU).

Comment: where i must use command `file`?

Comment: Use it in terminal (command prompt).